# Reauthorize Google Container Registry GCR to read from Github

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, authorization, docker-registry

When trying to create a new Build Trigger I get the following response, after selecting Github as a source:

> Google Cloud Platform was not authorized to list repositories. Its access was most likely revoked.

Unfortunately I have no options on this page to do anything about it.

On Github the Authorization is still on Approved, when looking into "Third-party application access policy".

I created other triggers before. So it was working until today.

Is there way to reauthorize GCR to access Github?

Comment: Did you try revoking the access to google cloud platform in github account and reauthenticate?  At what stage are you seeing this error? This could be an issue if you have the very large number of repositories which  the google API may not be able to handle. As a workaroud, try using a [github machine user](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#machine-users) to break down repositories in smaller ones.